# Curve fitting of a list and exclude some figure

Tags: fitting

[image]

I am a fresher of Mathematica and trying to program a list of digits. When I plot the diagram of the list, it shows that the figure at 12 is much larger than the others. Does anyone have idea on it? Or can I limit the maximum value and then plot the figure?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Please provide actual data and code, not just images. Your question is yet unclear - do you want to filter your list?

Answer (score 2):

> shows that the figure at 12 is much larger than the others

that is correct. It is because the data at that location is much larger than the others. You can limit the plot range as follows

```
data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, 20];
data[[10]] = 10^14; (*insert large point*)
ListPlot[data, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now using specific plot range

```
 ListPlot[data, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 1.1}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

btw, you can use `ListLinePlot[data, PlotRange -> {Automatic, {0, 1.1}}]` instead of `ListPlot`

Answer (score 1):

you can remove the large value like this:

```
 ListPlot[ Select[ data , Abs[#[[2]]]<10^4& ] , Joined->True]
```

Comment: Much Thanks!!!!